# Source Bashrc has no effect

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I am extremely new to any kind of software development. Last week I installed Bash on Ubuntu on Windows to work on some coding for work. Unfortunately I did something wrong and had to reinstall everything. 
I was almost done with reinstalling Bash on Ubuntu, when I accidentally closed the screen. Now I get exactly the same errors as previously, but I definately do not want to reinstall this again...

So what changed? Before my terminal was colored purple and green. Now, I only get white colors in the terminal. It looks something like this:

[Image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3SSS.png)

Furthermore, after googling it said to apply

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

But then I get the error: "No such file or directory". Bash is installed because it does actually give

```
which bash -> /bin/bash
```

I also read that perhaps it could be my path, where $PATH gives me

```
bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

I was hoping that you'd have an idea what could be wrong, and best how to resolve it. I definately do not want to reinstall it AGAIN, because it took me too long already.

Hope you can help me!
Cheers,
Wessel

Comment: Are you following a particular guide you could link? Bash should come installed by default on Ubuntu. Additionally, your bash profile could be in any of `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Bash is default installed with the ubuntu afaik

Comment: Further more when u open a bash prompt bashrc is automatically executed. You only need to source if you changed the bashrc file. Also you can check ohmyzsh https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh if you want a fancy terminal

Comment: It also doesnt seem to find the profile... all of the programs that I installed such as miniconda, it also is unable to find the command. It just says command undefined, which before this it did work! So its not that I want fancy colors, it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: So perhaps it is good to know that I was using miniconda to initiate an environment, and that I couldnt deactivate this environment using source deactivate. Then I accidentally clicked the screen, and ever since it doesnt work

Comment: ~/.bashrc might not appear on a vanilla machine. You might need to create one.

Comment: Customizing your interactive shell isn't particularly topical here, unless you're writing software for the purpose and have a question about a specific problem you hit in its development; StackOverflow is **exclusively** for questions *"unique to software development"* (combined with other bullet points in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic using an **and** condition, making it necessary, not sufficient). [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) are much more appropriate StackExchange sites for this class of question.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Jack, the configuration for bash should be in ~/.bashrc or similar.
What files are listed if you enter this command?

```
ls -a ~/
```

If you see .bashrc, you can edit it.

Here some ideas on colouring your prompt
https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/

Comment: Actually this file is not there! So is that bad? Haha, what then?

Comment: Even if you don't see .bashrc, you can edit it (and create it in the process)

Comment: But how does that solve the problem of bash not being able to find my programs anymore? Thats the biggest issue, not the colors haha

Comment: You can add a program location to PATH like this 'export PATH=$PATH:/foldername/foldername'.. Then bash will look for programs there too